# Is there a way to prevent python turicreate from using subdirectories as training data?

Tags: python, turi-create

I'm getting my training data using...

`turicreate.image_analysis.load_images('TrainingData', with_path=True)`

*TrainingData/* has all my training data using the folder names as labels...

`data['label'] = data['path'].apply(lambda path: os.path.dirname(path.split('/')[-1]))`

That gets the last directory... the problem is that turicreate is going deeper than I'm expecting it to.

The directory structure looks like this...

- **TrainingData/**

  - **Model1/**

    - **ADirectory/** // <== here's the problem (I want to ignore this directory)

      - img1_s.jpg
    - img1.jpg
    - img2.jpg
  - **Model2/**
- runTuriCreate.py

At the moment turicreate is going into TrainingData which is what I'd expect... but it's using all subdirectories as well as the directories I want to model.

Is there a way to do this?

**EDIT: I found that you can add recursive=False to the load_images function call. The problem with this is that I AM using recursion... just recursion with one depth level strictly.**